# How to test React using jest with redux connect on the nested child?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

If anyone could share if there's a way of unit testing react using jest with redux connect on the nested child, I prefer the easiest implementation

```
import React from 'react'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { CoreLayoutWithRedux } from '../index'
import createStore from '../../../redux/create'

describe('(Layout) Core', () => {
  let _props, _spies, _wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    _spies = {}
    _props = {
      store: createStore({}),
      isOnline: false,
      notifications: [],
      ...bindActionCreators({
        notificationDismiss : (_spies.notificationDismiss = sinon.spy()),
        notificationDispatch : (_spies.notificationDispatch = sinon.spy()),
        updateConnectionStatus: (_spies.updateConnectionStatus = sinon.spy())
      }, _spies.dispatch = sinon.spy())
    }
    _wrapper = shallow(<CoreLayoutWithRedux {..._props}><div /></CoreLayoutWithRedux>)
  })

  test('Should render as a <CoreLayout>.', () => {
    expect(_wrapper.is('CoreLayout')).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Here's what I have done so far, but the problem is when we need Store for the nested child

Comment: Share the code showing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
let connectedWrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}>
                <SomeContainerOfYours {...yourprops}/>
            </Provider>);

let wrapper = connectedWrapper.find(ComponentYouWantToTest);
```

Now you can interact with your connected nested component.